# Pointers and typedef in C

Tags: c, pointers, typedef

In C,

```
int* a, b;
```

Will make `a` an integer pointer and b an integer.

What about this? Is `b` an integer or an integer pointer?

```
typedef int* foo;
foo a, b;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C, `typedef` is not a preprocessor directive: unlike `#define`, it is not a textual substitution. It gives an alternative name to an existing type, so both `a` and `b` will be of the same type - namely, `foo`, which is an alias for `int*`. Moreover, you can write this:

```
foo a, *b;
```

to make `a` an `int*` and `b` an `int**`.

Comment: It's *slightly* misleading to say that `typedef` "creates a named type". It creates a new name for an existing type.

Comment: The type `int*`, or `struct s*` for that matter, already exists. You have to be able to name the type to `typedef` it.